# Thickness option in FillingStyle

Tags: plotting

I have the following `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, .3}, {4, 6}}, Filling -> Axis, 
FillingStyle -> {Thickness[0.008], Black}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[20], Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot1]

I have a problem with the lines below the points: They are too thin. How to change the Thickness propperly? `FillingStyle -> {Thickness[0.008], Black},` seems not to be correct.

Comment: Perhaps try using FillingStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.008], Black]?  This will remove possible ambiguity.

Comment: In your case, you _do_ need to use `Directive` with `FillingStyle`, but you _don't_ need it for `LabelStyle`; i.e., `FillingStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.008], Black], LabelStyle -> 30` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually a good idea to group multiple "styling" options into a single [Directive](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Directive.html).  This removes any possible ambiguities that can arise.  When simply using a list

```
PlotStyle -> {d1, d2, d3,...}
```

this specifies that successive directives *di* should be used cyclically for successive objects.

[image: using Directive to specify a style]